# Multiline matrix equation

Tags: equations, matrices

I try to create this multiline matrix equation:
[image]

But for some reason, `\\` doesn't work. This is what I get:

```
%
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
H^{TE,inc}_{y1}(1-R^{TE})\\[6pt]
-H^{TE,inc}_{x1}(1-R^{TE})
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
Y^{TE,in}_{xx} & Y^{TE,in}_{xy}\\[6pt]
Y^{TE,in}_{yx} & Y^{TE,in}_{yy}
\end{pmatrix}
%
\begin{pmatrix}
E^{TE,inc}_{x1}(1+R^{TE})\\[6pt]
E^{TE,inc}_{y1}(1+R^{TE})
\end{pmatrix} 
\\[6pt]
\text{and} \\[6pt]
\begin{pmatrix}
H^{TM,inc}_{y1}(1-R^{TM})\\[6pt]
-H^{TM,inc}_{x1}(1-R^{TM})
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
Y^{TM,in}_{xx} & Y^{TM,in}_{xy}\\[6pt]
Y^{TM,in}_{yx} & Y^{TM,in}_{yy}
\end{pmatrix}
%
\begin{pmatrix}
E^{TM,inc}_{x1}(1+R^{TM})\\[6pt]
E^{TM,inc}_{y1}(1+R^{TM})
\end{pmatrix} \\[6pt]
\label{eqch3_9}
\end{equation}
%
```

Comment: Should a single equation number be associated with both equations, or do you need separate equation numbers? Please advise.

Comment: I need a single number to be associated with both equations.

Comment: `\\\` never work inside `equation` ...

Comment: Actually it works, but not with the matrices =(

Answer (score 2):

Hope the below can meet your requirement:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
H^{TE,inc}_{y1}(1-R^{TE})\\[6pt]
-H^{TE,inc}_{x1}(1-R^{TE})
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
Y^{TE,in}_{xx} & Y^{TE,in}_{xy}\\[6pt]
Y^{TE,in}_{yx} & Y^{TE,in}_{yy}
\end{pmatrix}
%
\begin{pmatrix}
E^{TE,inc}_{x1}(1+R^{TE})\\[6pt]
E^{TE,inc}_{y1}(1+R^{TE})
\end{pmatrix} \nonumber\\
\intertext{and} 
\begin{pmatrix}
H^{TM,inc}_{y1}(1-R^{TM})\\[6pt]
-H^{TM,inc}_{x1}(1-R^{TM})
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
Y^{TM,in}_{xx} & Y^{TM,in}_{xy}\\[6pt]
Y^{TM,in}_{yx} & Y^{TM,in}_{yy}
\end{pmatrix}
%
\begin{pmatrix}
E^{TM,inc}_{x1}(1+R^{TM})\\[6pt]
E^{TM,inc}_{y1}(1+R^{TM})
\end{pmatrix}\label{eqch3_9}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you!